# Crawlera proxies not working with python selenium and Chrome Web driver

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, crawlera

I have just bought a plan from crawlera for proxies and according to their documentation using polipo is not working for me and according to polipo site, it is outdated already. How Can I use crawlera proxies in Selenium and Chrome web driver. Here is my standard proxy using code with selenium chrome web driver.

```
     chrome_path = os.path.join(dir, 'selenium','webdriver','chromedriver.exe')
     chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
     preferences={"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2, 'disk-cache-size': 4096 }
     chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', preferences)
     chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
     chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=https://[api key]:@proxy.crawlera.com:8010')
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,options=chrome_options) 
    self.driver.maximize_window()
```